# how to do vlookup in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, tidy

I have a data set like below

```
  first_column <- c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
second_column <- c("keep", "remove", "remove")

main.df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column); main.df

first_column second_column
1      value_1          keep
2      value_2        remove
3      value_3        remove

first_column <- c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
column1  <- c("si", "no", "na")
column2 <-  c(5, 2, 3)

vlookupdf  <- data.frame(first_column, column1, column2);  vlookupdf 
first_column column1 column2
1      value_1      si       5
2      value_2      no       2
3      value_3      na       3
```

I would like to remove the rows from `main.df` if `vlookupdf column1` is eather no or na

Expected Answer  from `main.df`

```
first_column second_column
1      value_1          keep
```

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `left_join` your dataframe and `filter` based on your criteria like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
main.df |>
  left_join(vlookupdf, by = 'first_column') |>
  filter(!(column1 %in% c("no", 'na'))) |>
  select(first_column, second_column) # if necessary
#>   first_column second_column
#> 1      value_1          keep
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In base R one approach is `match` and negated `%in%`:

```
main.df[match(vlookupdf[!(vlookupdf$column1 %in% c("no", "na")), "first_column"], main.df$first_column),]
```

Output

```
#  first_column second_column
# 1      value_1          keep
```